# iOS How to get the content offset of a view inside a scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Lets say I add 10 views to a scrollview. I obviously give them a rect inside of the scrollview. Is there any way to figure out what each item's offset is in the scrollview?

I'm guessing that probably isn't applicable here.  What I need in essence is, "If this item is at this content offset in the scrollview (meaning visible to the user in a certain area of the scrollview), then do this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view's frame is expressed in its superview coordinate system (bounds). That is, in your case for each view its content offset is `CGRectGetMinY(view.frame)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to find the current scroll position by looking at UIScrollView contentOffset

> The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view.

With the contentOffset, you can then compare this with the frame x and y coordinates of the content views and determine if they are onscreen or not.